# Passing pointers to another process

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr, marshalling

I’m trying to pass a pointer to a structure to another process I have created… I’m getting nothing but invalid pointer errors in the process I’m sending the pointer too… Is this even possible in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)?

My code for the sending process:

```
' Initialize unmanged memory to hold the struct.
Dim ptrSettings As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(EngineSettings))

' Copy the struct to unmanaged memory.
Marshal.StructureToPtr(EngineSettings, ptrSettings, False)

SendMessage(HWND, MSG_SETTINGS_STRUCT, 0, ptrSettings)
```

I'm overriding WinProc in the second process to receive the message in LParam:

```
EngineSettings = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, GetType(SettingsStruct)), SettingsStruct)

' Free the unmanaged memory.
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)
```

The pointer is the same value between both processes, here is the error in the second process:

The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Comment: My guess your running into memory protection, which means, you will have to find another way to communicate with the other process.  Besides your idea itself seems like a very poor idea.

Comment: if you think it's a poor idea than why not suggest another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes cannot normally share memory. Remember that *most* addresses are actually virtual addresses and do not point to a physical hardware location but instead a page and offset.

The win32 functions return pointers because they are running within your processes address space not a separate process.

See [Memory managment options in Win32](http://www.abstraction.net/content/articles/memory%20management%20options%20in%20win32.htm) for more information on how all native calls actually allocate memory in Win32 (at least from User mode code). The only thing not mentioned on that page is [Large-Page Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which creates non-standard pages and that cannot be paged to disk. Theses pages can be difficult to work with even in C/C++ so I highly recommend against using them from within the CLR.

You'll will probably want to use shared memory if you want to directly share this native struct. [Creating Named Shared Memory (Win32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: ok, thanks for providing more details... Justin had also recommended memory mapped files.

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest looking into memory mapped files for this kind of thing?  Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: interesting approach, i'll do some reading... i'd really like to know if my implementation is possible in CLR...

Comment: @Don, It isn't possible in Windows. AllocHGlobal doesn't allocate from a "global" heap. The term is for legacy purposes only. AllocHGlobal still eventually calls VirtualAlloc on any Win32 platform. Global heaps were part of the 16bit era.

Comment: thanks, some terms MS uses are very vague... along with the documentation on MSDN...

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the class to XML and `SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT)` it to a text box in the other application (you could pass the hwnd pretty easily using your current code since it's just a long). Then put a listener on the textbox changed event.

Comment: I understand what your trying to do, but it’s not really the approach I want to take. Thank you.